# Compiling c code programatically in linux terminal gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, terminal

I'm writing a c program on Linux that writes text into a file. I'm having trouble where i'M trying to use `system("gcc fileName.c")` to compile the new document i created into an executable. The file is getting the following input:

```
char Msg[100] = {"#include <stdio.h>\nint main();\n\nint main()\n{\n\n\treturn 0;\n}"};
```

clearly it has a `main()` function and yet it still gives me the following wall of error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 21 has invalid symbol index 22
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I compile it manually it works perfectly...

I'm very new to c so I'm not sure where I'm wrong, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

File contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main();

int main() 
{

     return 0;
}
```

when used `-c` output file contents:

`ELF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00(\00  \00\00\00GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2\00\00.symtab\00.strtab\00.shstrtab\00.text\00.data\00.bss\00.comment\00.note.GNU-stack\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00!\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00'\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00,\00\00\00\00\00\000\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00%\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\005\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Y\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Y\00\00\00E\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00p\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00  \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00x\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F1\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fffggg.c\00`

EDIT:
Full Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char nepCode[10];

    char PathOut[1035];
    char Msg[100] = {"#include <stdio.h>\nint main();\n\nint main()\n{\n\n\treturn 0;\n}"};
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    char fullPath[1035];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen("/bin/pwd", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
      printf("Failed to run command\n" );
      exit(1);
    }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        printf("Current working directory: %s", path);
        for(i = 0; i < 1035; i++)
        {
            PathOut[i] = path[i];
        }
    }

    printf("//Program by WolfyD\n//Creates a .c template file with your Neptun Code \n//in the folder from where it's run from");

    printf("\n\n\nPlease enter your NEPTUN CODE: ");

    nepCode[0] = '/';

    scanf("%s",nepCode);


    nepCode[6] = '.';
    nepCode[7] = 'c';

    int index = 0;
    int i2 = -1;
    for(index = 0; index < 1035; index++)
    {
        if(PathOut[index] != '\0')
        {
                fullPath[index] = PathOut[index];
        }
        else
        {


            if(i2 == -1)
            {
                index--;
                fullPath[index] = '/';
            }
            else
            {
                fullPath[index] = nepCode[i2];
            }
            i2++;
        }

    }


        FILE *f = fopen(fullPath, "ab");

        fputs(Msg,f);
        printf("File [ %s ] written to: %s\n\n",nepCode, fullPath);

        sleep(2);                

        char sysStr[100] = {"gcc -oofile.o -c "};
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(fullPath); i++)
        {
                sysStr[17 + i] = fullPath[i];
        }                        

        printf("%s\n\n\n",sysStr);
        system(sysStr);

        printf("\nOutput file [ ofile.o ] created\n\n");

        system("gcc -o output ofile.o");

  /* close */
    pclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

Please don't judge too harshly, I'm just learning c

EDIT:

update:

I decided to try the code out on my Win8 PC and i realized at least one of my problems was some garbage, but now i edited it slightly. On Windows i have MinGW and it writes a different message when i try to compile the o file into an executable:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.tex
t.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why is the code in an array of pointers? Wouldn't it be easier if you had it in just an array, like e.g. `char Msg[] = "...";`?

Comment: More regarding your problem, have you checked the output file? Have you tried compiling it manually?

Comment: Thanks, i got a bit confused between all the arrays, i fixed that but still, the problem is the same.
Yes i tried it manually in many ways, if i use the -c it creates an object file but i still can't compile that into executable.

Comment: Maybe the path used by the shell spawned by `system` and the path in your normal shell are different, so that the `gcc` command invoked by `system` is not the same as the one invoked by you manually executing it.

Comment: That was my guess, but how could i find out how it's different? The if i write it out using `printf()` or `echo` it looks perfectly the same as what i write in, even if i copy that out and use that manually

Comment: No, you may be right, when i tried copy-pasting `gcc -o ofile ofile.o` manually it gives me the same error

Comment: Create a script file, and call it with the `system` function in your program. In the script do e.g. `which gcc` or `echo $PATH`. Then compare the output from the script to what you get when running the script manually. The thing that worries my is the `/usr/lib/debug` output in the error message from the linker, and that tells me you have multiple installations of `gcc` on your system and which makes me think the `gcc` command executed from your program is not the same as the one executed manually.

Comment: If i add the code to my question could you possibly check if it has a major error in it? I'm not convinced, that i didn't mess it up just in any step of the code.

Comment: Your code is probably alright, the problem is most likely that you have *two* (or more) installations of GCC (in different locations), one that is invoked by `system("gcc ...")`, and another different installation is invoked when you run it manually in a shell.

Comment: Hmmm Thank you, I'll look in to how i could find that out, I'll edit when i have anything.
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: sadly no luck. I removed both gcc and gcc-4.8 from my system, reinstalled gcc and the same error occurs

Comment: The linker behaves like you have compiled a completely empty C-file (yes it's valid C) furthermore I miss the string 'main' in your o-file dump. I would double check if the file is not empty at the time you are starting the compiler

Comment: I added a 2 second sleep before and after creating the o file, that didn'T help but i might try adding a longer one, though I'm worried since my c# knowledge tought me that sleep will halt the program completely so i don'T know what's in the file at the time i try and compile it, is there a different kind of sleep in c?

Comment: Could you show how you pass from the char array `char Msg[100]= "..."` to `filename.c` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not  completely following your logic, put here are some possible problems:

First of all, where do you get the path from; this program may be simpler using command-line arguments than it is how you are doing it.

This means, you declare main as follows in your main file:
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )

In this form, argc is the number of arguments passed INCLUDING the file name, and argv[0] is a string holding your file's name.

So, rather than rely on the program to generate the file for you, you do it somewhat like this:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s %s\n", argv[0], "input_file output_file" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Do not add an extension to output_file.\n" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  unsigned int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen( argv[2] ); i++) {
    if (argv[2][i] == '\n' || argv[2][i] == '\0') {
      argv[2][i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  char format_string[150];
  sprintf( format_string, "gcc.exe -Wall -Wextra -c %s -o %s.o", argv[1], argv[2] );
  char format_string2[150];
  sprintf( format_string2, "gcc.exe %s -o %s.exe", argv[1], argv[2] );
  system( format_string );
  system( format_string2 );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With the above program, you just create the input file then pass the inpu file as the first argument and your output to the second one. This file does make two assumptions: input_file exists and the path to gcc is in your enviroment's path variable.

Finally, don't forget that main does NOT need a prototype.