# C compiling error

Tags: c, ubuntu

so i'm learning at the moment programming in C language. We are working with ubuntu, so i installed one at home, but i'm having a lot of problems while compiling.

for compiling i'm using gcc file_name.c

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main (){
 printf ("hello world\n");
}
```

but the thing is, it gives me this type of error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 21 has invalid symbol index 22
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What did i do wrong ? ty in advance for your time

Comment: Technically those aren't *compiler* errors but linker errors. Also technically, your program is neither a valid C nor a valid C++ program, as the `main` function is not declared properly. It should be declared as `int main(void)` in C.

Comment: humm... but in my school, we write like that in our computer's and it works

Comment: Regarding the errors, do you have a 64-bit installation?

Comment: It's not correct to write like that, and you should tell that to whoever told you to do it. The declaration of `main` is clearly stated in the C specification, and it must return an `int`, and either have a `void` argument or an `int` and a `char*[]` (or `char**`) argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Actually it's a valid C89 source code... it should compile fine (but with warnings) with gcc -std=c89 for example

Comment: Also, if you write `which gcc` as a command, what's the output? Then if you `ls -l` on the output from the previous command, what is the output then?

Comment: First you can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886020/compiling-c-code-programatically-in-linux-terminal-gcc) and can you send your program output when you use `gcc -c`.

Comment: It's likely related to you developing environment and not the error in the source code(since it does support C89 standard and use `-std=c89` just to see if it works) Try to reinstall the gcc.

Comment: `gcc` implements the 1989/1990 C standard by default, with GNU extensions. That dialect of C has the "implicit `int`" rule, which makes `main()` legal (and equivalent to `int main()`). C99 dropped that rule, making `main()` illegal (actually a syntax error). The modern form `int main(void)` is valid in all dialects of C, and there's no good reason not to use it (or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`), even if your compiler might let you get away with something else.

Comment: Anyway, it is indicating that the linker cannot find a `main` function. Try `objdump -t your_file.o | grep main` and make sure you are getting output with `main` in it without any weird symbols. You should run `gcc -c yourfile.c` before.

Comment: I think OS use relocation table to find referenced functions (like printf) so this error related to linking with standard C library.

Comment: Are you certain that `gcc file_name.c` is the *exact* command you're using?

Comment: @KeithThompson yes i am sir!

Comment: @EugeneSh. i did what you suggest. It didn't show any error, but when i tried to run the file it said i didn't had permission to do it.

Comment: @Jack it gave the same error sir. I think i will try reinstall the gcc and see what happens

Comment: Try it and see if it works

Comment: @Jack sir, after i installed this  'sudo apt-get install mingw32' it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct code but your programming environment may not be setup properly.

Comment: Try compiling with `gcc -o main filename.c`.

Comment: @BinaryJudy: It's likely a issue on the linker/compiler not the source code (it's fine).

Comment: @Jack how do i solve it, do you know ? :S i'ts my first time using linux so, it's all kinda new to me

Comment: @bluewolfxD Maybe check out [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux) tutorial and see if it gives you any insight. It uses some other options when compiling that I'm not familiar with. it also shows the install package which may be different from what you did.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @congusbongus This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And fot the compilation use:

```
gcc file.c -o compiledFile
```

Comment: How does compiling to rather an object file helps? it's a issue on his linker/compiler instead of

Comment: @Jack: That doesn't compile to an object file; it merely specifies the name of the executable file (which defaults to `a.out`). If you wanted to compile to an object file, you'd use `gcc -c file.c -o file.o` But you're right, it's not likely to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `main` should return an `int`, but there seems to be a problem with your compiler installation. While you do not get it fixed, since you are doing simple things, you can also use an online compiler such as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

So guys... i searched a little bit more and i found that i needed to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

after i did this, the gcc file.c command worked and it created a a.out file

after that it worked just fine.
Ty all for you time and sugestions!

Answer (score -4):

You should type `void` or `int` with a return value at the end of the programm:

```
void main() {
}
```

or

```
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

and use Visual Studio. It is better :)

Comment: `main` is never `void`.

Comment: And the last suggestion is a nonsense.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler permits `void main()` as an extension. There is no good reason to use it rather than the universally correct `int main(void)`.